# Android Get Calling class fields

Tags: android, reflection

I have an android application that calls my method via `DexClassLoader` `loadClass` and `invoke()`.

I need to access the fields of the class that call my method from my method itself.

I managed to get the name of the calling method via the Stack Trace but I already know that so it's not useful and I don't manage to access the class itself from the stack trace, only his name.

Do you have an idea of how could I be able to get the value of the fields of the calling class from the method I control?

I think there is a Reflection class that could be able to do that in basic java but I can't find something like that on android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Lena Bru, I finally found the answer it was :

```
Field[] fields = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass("com.example.callerApp.MainActivity").getFields();
```